# How to access a gadget serial interface with dotnet core 3.0 on ARM device?

Tags: .net, linux, .net-core, serial-port, arm

I have an ARM device that is connected via USB to my PC.
On Windows, it is listed as a serial port on COM4 as an example.

The interface is implemented with the Linux Gadget Serial driver on the ARM device. Regarding to the documentation, it only simulates a Serial connection for attached devices.

With dotnet core 3.0 it is now possible to use the System.IO.Ports package to open up a serial connection on Linux too.

The problem I am facing is that it seems the Gadget Serial device is no real serial port.

For instance when I list all available Portnames with `SerialPort.GetPortNames()` the Gadget port `/dev/ttyGS0` is missing.

This is the output on the ARM device:

```
/dev/ttyO2
/dev/ttyO0
/dev/ttyO3
/dev/ttyO1
```

Does this mean the `/dev/ttyGS0` is no real Serial Port and I can't use it like this?

```
var port = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyGS0");
```

I tried it that way and this is the exception I got.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: Invalid argument
```

How could I access the `/dev/ttyGS0` device to read and write data with dotnet core?

Thanks!

Comment: Would love to hear an answer...

Comment: Hello. As far as I remember was the solution not to use the SerialPort class for that. The reason for that is that the Gadget Serial is no real Serial Port. It only simulates a serial connection for the host device. To read from it you need to use a normal USB implementation.

Comment: Could you define "normal USB implementation" for me? Couldn't he just use System.IO.File to read and write from the file?

Comment: To be honest. I didn't remember anymore how I did it. I think I used a NuGet package to access a USB device.